# Struts2 letting an interceptor not run for certain classes

Tags: java, struts2

I have a custom interceptor. I would like this interceptor to run on all action invocations except a few. I would like to program this (for extendibility/clarity) rather than using if/else statements checking the action's name inside the interceptor's `intercept()` method itself.

I think it might be done with the "exclude method" capacities of Struts2, but I'm stuck with the exact details. I think my interceptor needs to extend the `MethodFilterInterceptor`, but it has 2 intercept methods and the API is not very helpful in saying what each should do:

> protected abstract String doIntercept(ActionInvocation invocation)
>
> ```
>       Subclasses must override to implement the interceptor logic.
> ```
>
> String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation)
>
> ```
>       Override to handle interception
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking it the other way around:

instead of checking the Action name (or better, the `instanceOf` to check for a specific Action `Interface`) to see if it should do some business, simply tell that Action to use a different Interceptor Stack.

For example, you can say that your Custom Stack (the Stack containing your Interceptor) is the default (then applied to all actions), but that ActionA, ActionB and ActionX run with the DefaultStack...

Comment: I didn't think of this, but it seems like a very clean solution. Thanks! I really like how everyone who will read the struts.xml will clearly see that certain actions will not use certain interceptors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Interceptors shouldn't extend ActionSupport, *yuck*. They're not actions.
2. Mark the actions it should (or should not) run for with an interface or annotation and check for that in the interceptor.

Comment: How can I check, inside the intercept() method, which "interfaces" the current action class has, I only have an action context, not the actual action class itself?

Comment: @user1884155 ?! Of course you do--it's how basically all the framework interceptors work, by checking to see if the action is an `instanceOf`.

Comment: Ok, what's the exact syntax inside an interceptor to get the action then? is it: if(actionContext instanceof myInterface) { ... }

Comment: @user1884155 ... https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/repo?p=struts.git;a=blob;f=core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletConfigInterceptor.java;h=df45347b0f9d452f1430fe69b9e6174b71a3a906;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure why getAction() returned a "useless" object but now I see you can use it to check for classes/interfaces.

Comment: @user1884155 It's not useless, it's the action.